reg delete command to delete notepad.exe from registry is not working
reg delete command to delete notepad.exe from registry is not working. please find below command
reg delete "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store" -RegValue notepad++.exe /f
I want to delete the value not the the key from registry
The value path is HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store
The value name is D:\Software\npp.8.6.2.portable.x64\notepad++.exe
I tried to deleted value in registry but I am observing below error
Error :
ERROR: Invalid key name.
Type "REG QUERY /?" for usage.
Value Exists
The notepad++.exe value was not found in the registry.
Press any key to continue . . .
Tried Command :
reg delete "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store" /v notepad++.exe /f
Details :
I want to delete the value not the the key from registry
The value path is HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store
The value name is D:\Software\npp.8.6.2.portable.x64\notepad++.exe
